# Is there a book on mathematical logic with a similar style to mathematician Terence Tao's book "Analysis 1"?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, book-recommendation

I am looking for a mathematical logic textbook that I can study on my own. However, I am not very proficient in English. To give you an idea of my English level, I can read children's books such as "Matilda" and math textbooks in English.

In particular, I really like Terence Tao's book "Analysis 1". This book provides very detailed explanations of proofs.

However, the problem is that books with a lot of everyday English language are difficult for me to read. This includes books in the philosophy category.

I found that books with titles like "A Friendly Introduction to Logic" were actually more difficult for me to read. The more explanations there were, the more difficult it was for me as a non-native English speaker.

So, I was wondering if there are any mathematical logic textbooks that are easy for me to read?

I've searched Amazon and Google extensively, but I haven't found a book that's perfect for me. I considered purchasing Enderton's "Mathematical Introduction to Logic," which seems to be highly recommended, but the proofs aren't detailed enough.

I'm hoping to find a book that's perfect for me, but since Terence Tao's book was so good, I'm looking for something similar.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please have a look at Stephen Kleene's [Mathematical Logic](https://m.doverpublications.com/0486425339.html). I really liked the detailed pace as well as a narrative style that didn't lose the plot so far that I have read.

Comment: Kleene is a classic, but it's pretty outdated at this point. I wouldn't recommend it. Ju so: can you say a bit more about your goals? Why do you want to learn about mathematical logic? Logic is a big field, and knowing your motivations will help people recommend books.

Comment: I found Goldrei, Propositional and Predicate calculus, A model of argument, to be a very good introduction. It’s a bit wordy though.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I somehow became interested in the foundations of mathematics. I learned about mathematicians such as Russell, Cantor, and Frege. I also learned about Gödel's incompleteness theorem and read related books, but I couldn't fully understand it. So, I wanted to know more about the detailed proof. My goal is to find out how far I can study. Concepts such as completeness and soundness in logic also seem interesting to me. However, I am struggling because my English skills are not good enough. There seem to be good books available, but they are too difficult for me to read.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Do you have any book recommendations?

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods  Thanks. I bought it.

Comment: @Porky I'm studying it now

Comment: @juso, this would be a good book, but as already noted, you need to grab a more modern and concise book side by side. This would be a good venture.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [Beginning Mathematical Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl) Study Guide, especially §3.4 and 3.5 which give reviews of a range of possible texts to explore.